# Image slider using ngx-slick-carousel in Angular 9 not rendering image

Tags: angular

I have created a simple ngx slick carousel code for sliding images. But after loading it in a browser the images don't load. Below is my code.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { SlickCarouselModule } from 'ngx-slick-carousel';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SlickCarouselModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

  })
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  images = [
    {'image': "assets/images/FBI.jpg"},
    {'image': "assets/images/SAS.jpg"},
    {'image': "assets/images/GIGN.jpg"},
    {'image': "assets/images/GSG9.jpg"}
  ];

  slideConfig = {
    "slidesToShow" : 1,
    "slidesToScroll" : 1,
    "dots" : true,
    "infinite" : false,
    // "autoRotate" : true,
    // "autoRotateAfter" : 5000,
    "autoplay" : true,
    "autoplaySpeed" : 1000
  };


}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div>
  <h1 style="text-align: center; text-decoration: underline; color: ivory; background-color: black;">Welcome to R6 tab</h1>
</div>


<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 btn btn-primary">
      Image Slider
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr style="background-color: black;"/>


<div class="row">
  <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
    <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let image of images" class="slide">
      <img src="{{image}}.jpg" width="99%" height="680px" >
    </div>
  </ngx-slick-carousel>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the console/network tab to see the error.  Its probably saying throwing a 404 error for "{{image}}.jpg"

This line is the problem

```html
<img src="{{image}}.jpg" width="99%" height="680px" >
```

Angular will not interpolate the data in a property that way, and even if it did your array items are returning `{'image': "assets/images/FBI.jpg"}`

You need the `.image` property of the item you are looping through. That is the string you want, and it already has the file extension in it too.

```html
<img [src]="image.image" width="99%" height="680px" >
```

Angular still may complain about the URL not being sanitized, if so you will need to look into creating a Safe URL to pass to the img src https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: Yes, {{image}}.jpg was showing 404 status. And the image [src]="image.image" worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now when I am integrating this sliding image part into another project, the carousel part is not causing any effect. The images are just stacking up one above the other.

Comment: Without looking at it, it could be you missed some CSS

Comment: could you take a look at the link below for the full code. I created another question for this problem. Frankly there isn't much CSS involved here. It's just the height,width.margin, border and text-align.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62848464/ngx-slick-carousel-not-working-after-integrating-in-a-project

Comment: I got it. But the dots at the bottom are still not visible, and I haven't been able to get the navigation arrows to show. Any idea on how to do that? (the arrows)