# ngx slick carousel not working after integrating in a project

Tags: angular

I created an ngx slick carousel seperately and it was working fine. But when I integrated in into a project, the pictures just stacked one above the other. What can I do here.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SlickCarouselModule } from 'ngx-slick-carousel';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SlickCarouselModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = '**********';

  images = [
    {'image': "assets/images/FBI.jpg"},
    {'image': "assets/images/SAS.jpg"},
    {'image': "assets/images/GIGN.jpg"},
    {'image': "assets/images/GSG9.jpg"},
    {'image': "assets/images/Spetsnaz.jpg"}
  ];

  slideConfig = {
    "slidesToShow" : 1,
    "slidesToScroll" : 1,
    "dots" : true,
    "infinite" : true,
    "autoplay" : true,
    "autoplaySpeed" : 3000,
    "showArrow" : false
  };
  
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="logo">
      Logo will be here
    </div>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <button class="nav-btn">******</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">********</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">***********</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">**************</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">***************</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">*************</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">*************</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">************</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">**************</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">***</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">*******************</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">***************</button>
      <button class="nav-btn">*****************</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="header">
      <input class="search-box" type="text" name="main-search-box" placeholder="Search Your Question">
      <button class="btn">**********</button>
      <button class="btn">**********</button>
      <button class="btn">****</button>
      <button class="btn">***************</button>
      <button class="btn">*********</button>
    </div>
    <div class="sliding-image">
      <div class="row">
        <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
          <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let image of images" class="slide">
            <img [src]="image.image" alt="slidingImage" width="100%" height="570px">
          </div>
        </ngx-slick-carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <button class="btn">*****</button>
      <button class="btn">************</button>
      <button class="btn">************</button>
      <button class="btn">**********</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

The stack is only visible when I put the height in percentage and when the screen's width is decreased. And there some error showing in the network console as well.

[image]

Below is the screenshot of the isolated image slider project:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their docs say you need JQuery (which is not great for something that claims to be an Angular plugin...)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel

Your console error says you are missing JQuery, so its likely you didn't follow the set up properly to include JQuery.

The docs say to install jquery via npm

```
$ npm install jquery --save
```

And then add it to `scripts` in your `angular.json` file

```
 "scripts": [
    ...
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js",
    ...
  ]
```

Note, Angular might have a few `scripts` sections in that file for testing and normal running of the app.  Its possible you didn't put it in both.

Comment: As you mentioned I might have made a mistake while installing jquery, I re-created whole project and the image sliding is working now. But the dots at the bottom are still not visible. And I have been unable to show the navigation arrow. Any idea with that?

Comment: Maybe css or your image are too big.  right click and inspect the dom and see if they are there and just behind the image or below the edge of the screen.

Comment: You were right. It was in the css. I just had to add a bit padding below the image. Thanks.

Comment: But do you have any idea how to show arrows at either ends of the image.